# Do not close DialogPreference onClick if condition not met

Tags: android, onclick, dialog-preference

I have need for AutoCompliteTextView in PreferenceActivity so I extended DialogPreference. My auto-complite is expecting from (helping) user to enter country name. I'm fine if user press Cancel or enters no values, however I would like to ensure that proper name is entered before dialog is closed. I tried to override onClick as

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (!validator.isValid(textView.toString())) {
            onDialogClosed(false);
        } else {
            //do something here
            super.onClick(dialog, which);
        }
    }
```

also with onDialogClosed

```
@Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        if (validator.isValid(textView.toString())) {
            //do something here
            super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a user clicks on a dialog button, the dialog is closing, and there is nothing you can do to stop it.

The only thing I can think of that you could try is to call `getDialog()` on the `DialogPreference`, cast that to `AlertDialog`, then call `getButton()` to retrieve your positive button, and disable it, enabling it later when the input is valid.

Comment: I do not see where this should be done, onCreateDialogView and onPrepareDialogBuilder is too early as dialog is just build therefore null, onClick is too late since button click happen. Am I missing something?

Comment: @peter_budo: If nothing else, you are missing the first 11 words of my second paragraph: "The only thing I can think of that you could try". I have never attempted to impose validation on a `DialogPreference`. However, `onBindDialogView() and `showDialog()` would seem like candidates worth trying.

Comment: I seen it, I'm just trying to get some reasonable user experience (well at least by me), as I believe that just providing ListView or Spinner users from countries like United Kingdom or United States would hate me since these are somewhere at the end of 230+ long list of countries.

Comment: @peter_budo: I am not saying that your goal is wrong. I hope you succeed. However, I am saying that "am I missing something" implies that I am somehow intentionally withholding critical information, when in reality I am merely trying to help, based upon my non-validation experience with `DialogPreference` and general background with the Android SDK. If I had a sample of what you want to show you, I would have linked to it. My apologies for having an incomplete answer.

Comment: No, no that wasn't my intention. It was more of writer question that due to my lesser knowledge I could overlook/misunderstand something. I apology for this confusion.

Comment: I can post a code snippet (I'm not sure if the answer edit is ok).

Answer (score 9):

I also faced the problem, that Android does not provide a built-in way to check up a newly entered preference value BEFORE the preference dialog is closed. A check up performed after the dialog is closed (what the [`boolean onPreferenceChange`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) accomplishes), can only discover that the value is incorrect and the app should prevent it from being saved, but this seems rather inconvenient. Just imagine that a user made a typo, new value is not saved, but the dialog is closed, and the user is informed that he/she must repeat the process from very beginning. It surely should be fixed.

When it comes to a problem in programming, it's better to provide a code for solution. This is why I'm posting the answer with the solution ready for copy&paste. It follows the obvious idea from one of the answers above, whereas it does not deal with reflections as the other provided code-snippet implies.

```
public class CustomEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference
{
  // if true, this preference requires new values to be checked for conformance to e-mail syntax
  private boolean isEmail = false; 

  public CustomEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);

    // set isEmail either from custom XML-attributes (look up through attrs)
    // or just by key
    // if(getKey().equals(KNOWN_EMAIL_PREF))
    //   isEmail = true;
  }

  /**
   * Checks if newValue conforms to a specific rule/syntax.
   * Returns error code equal to resource ID of corresponding error message if the value is incorrect,
   * or 0 if the validation was successful
   *
   * @param  newValue  a string with new preference value that needs a check-up
   * @return    integer error code equal to error message resource id
   */
  private int isValid(String newValue)
  {
    int result = 0; // no error

    if(isEmail) 
    {
      if(!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(newValue).matches())
      {
        result = R.string.invalid_email;
      }
    }
    // ...
    // other check-ups if necessary

    return result;
  }

  @Override
  protected void showDialog(Bundle state)
  {       
    super.showDialog(state);

    final AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog)getDialog();

    final EditText edit = getEditText();

    d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {            
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
        int errorCode = isValid(edit.getText().toString());
        Boolean canCloseDialog = (errorCode == 0);

        if(canCloseDialog)
        {
          d.dismiss();
          onDialogClosed(true);
        }
        else
        {
          String errorMessage = getContext().getString(errorCode);
          Toast t = Toast.makeText(getContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          t.show();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I think the code is pretty much self-explaining. If a user fills in the field with incorrect e-mail, and presses OK button, then the dialog remains open and an error message is shown via toast.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, by using `reflection`, I achieved what you said.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if(!validate(arg)){
        try {
            // do not close
            Field field = dialog.getClass().getSuperclass()
                    .getDeclaredField("mShowing");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(dialog, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show some error in a dialog instead of disabling the button then you need to create a class CustomEditTextPreference that extends EditTextPreference

below is code snippet

```
public class CustomEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference  {
EditText setPasswordEditText;
private Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

public CustomEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    setPasswordEditText = this.getEditText();
}

@Override
protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    super.showDialog(state);

    alertDialog = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    Button positiveButton = alertDialog
            .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str = setPasswordEditText.getText().toString();
            if (/*condition not met*/) {
                showError();
            } else {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the onPrepareDialogBuilder() inside the DialogPreference